# Openquery within openquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is that possible to do a `openquery` within an `openquery`?

I have error while calling the openquery from MySQL Workbench via SQL Server from the following:

```
select * from openquery ([ABS],
         'select * from sales_payments 
          where receipt_id not in 
                (select * from openquery ([ABS], ''select distinct receipt_id from receipt''))
         ')
```

Comment: THINK about your code. OPENQUERY will send a statement to the specified database engine. That engine has no knowledge of the name "ABS" that you use in your query. But here there is no need to attempt to embed another openquery usage as already indicated. And for future reference, phrases like "I get an error" are not helpful to anyone. Get an error? Then include the exact error message you get - all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `INNER JOIN` instead of `NOT IN`?

```
SELECT * FROM openquery ([ABS],
     'SELECT * FROM sales_payments AS s
     INNER JOIN  receipt AS r 
     ON s.receipt_id =r.receipt_id
     WHERE r.receipt_id IS NULL')
```

Or simply :

```
SELECT * FROM openquery ([ABS],

'SELECT * FROM sales_payments AS s
 WHERE s.receipt_id NOT IN  (SELECT distinct receipt_id FROM receipt)')
```